# Java-Creating User-Generated JButtons

Tags: java, list, tabs, jbutton

Thanks for trying to help.  First off, I'm trying to create a sort of list-program that can allow you to create, manage, and view various lists.  However, I ran into a problem when I was deciding how to implement changing the lists.  I wanted to do something similar to the way most internet browsers work in the form of tabs, or even the way Notepad++ works..  Just have all the opened lists displayed under/above the menu bar.  However, I am unsure how to implement that.  I don't know how to accurately create new instances of opened lists in the form of a clickable button, or even add those to the top.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

Comment: @canickr  That was quite helpful, and I did not know tabs already existed in swing.  However, if I wanted to allow someone to create a new tab without that tab already being there, how would I do that?The code for creating a tab is this:  JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();  Therefore, how would I create a tab that doesn't have a name since I wouldn't know how many the user would create?  Does that make sense?

Comment: You can add tabs dynamically as needed.